# VBT and MOT at the same time!

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, resonance

In the SNAr reaction, it is said that the electron withdrawing groups should be at the ortho or para position for the effective electron delocalization to take place, and we draw Kekule's structure to justify it.

But can we justify it on the basis of Molecular Orbital Theory?

Comment: Yes. VB and MOT are different developments of the same theory, in the limit they are identical. So yes, if it can be justified in VBT it can also be justified in MOT.  I leave the details to the reader.